# Which algorithm does Python use for multiplication?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, multiplication, python-internals

The list of possible algorithms for multiplication is quite long:

1. Schoolbook long multiplication
2. Karatsuba algorithm
3. 3-way Toom–Cook multiplication
4. k-way Toom–Cook multiplication
5. Mixed-level Toom–Cook
6. Schönhage–Strassen algorithm
7. Fürer's algorithm

Which one is used by Python by default and why? When does it switch to a "better performance" algorithm?

Comment: Python source is available for you to go through and find out if you really need to. And why are you wondering? Plain curiosity, or do you have some other problem that you think might depend on this?

Comment: it's the XY problem can you specify the real problem you have?

Comment: I was watching an MIT video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCaXlAaN2uE&index=11&list=PLUl4u3cNGP61Oq3tWYp6V_F-5jb5L2iHb) about possible multiplication methods and the professor said that it normally uses Schoolbook long multiplication but for larger n as an input Python switches to better algorithms. Hence my question: when does it switch and why not use better algorithms as default.